# Do algorithms sort integers and strings with the same time consistency?

Tags: sorting

I know this might be a silly question but suppose an algorithm sorts 100,000 integers in 5 seconds.  Will the same algorithm sort 100,000 strings in 5 seconds as well or will their sorting times be different?

Comment: how about you benchmark? (the answer is no, mostly...).

Comment: The issue here is the length of the strings you are sorting, if they are small and can be compared to the size of an integer, depending on the algorithm of course, they can be very close if not the same, however usually a string takes more to compare than an integer would. Due in part to how strings are compared in general and the fact that integers can be compared in as little as one instruction on the CPU.

Comment: Comparing two integers is one single operation on most processors (i.e. runs very fast and in constant time). Comparing strings does not run in constant time, and for very very long strings which are mostly the same the comparison could take longer than for simple, short strings for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing strings is more expensive than comparing integers. The integer comparison is an operation that usually happens in the CPU. On the other hand, a comparison of strings needs to be implemented in software. Hence the comparison of strings can take as many operations as characters there are in a string.

--dmg

Answer (score 1):

Q: Do algorithms sort integers and strings with the same time consistency?

A: If you mean ["asymptotic"/"Big O notation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation): Yes.  Strings will obviously take longer ... but *proportionately* longer.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no.  Sorting strings will take far longer, usually, than sorting integers.

Consider sorting "paper" and "papa" -- you'd need to find that "paper" was greater than "papa" by comparing the first 4 characters.  This can get even longer with larger strings, especially phrases.

In contrast, an integer comparison will take a single instruction.

To do sorting, you need to do these kind of comparisons repeatedly; so sorting strings is almost always going to take much longer.

Answer (score 0):

The string will take more time.The integers are compared as a set of bitwise operations.When it comes to the string,the each byte or character is to be compared with equal operations as needed for a integer.

In effect, sorting a set of strings will involve comparing the total number of characters in all strings,in the worst case. The worst case is that all strings are same.Every string must be traversed till the end to make sure it is equal(strcmp() compares this way)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are sorting them by dictionary order, and with quick sort. You write your own comparison function to compare your strings and integers.

Integers are quite simple to compare, its value is its index while with string, you need to compare by its content. We do know that quick sort runs at an average time complexity of O(nlogn), with worst being O(n^2), and that happens when the pivot chosen is the minimum or maximum of the current partition. We'll assume it all goes well, and we got average case for now.

The variable to time complexity is your comparison function, the integer one is quite fast O(1), while comparing strings comes down to worst case of O(min(len(a), len(b)), best case of O(1), when the first character is different.

So yes, it's slower, but not that bad considering they're strings, also worst-case are those that rarely happens. (Like what Barney Goven mentioned, comparing two similar strings. )

When talking about time complexity of algorithm, we're generally talking about its growth when data set get bigger. So like what paulsm4 said, it's proportionately longer.